# 'max.print' option in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with 178 rows and 14 columns.  When I print it into the R-console, it only shows me 71 rows, despite the `max.print` option being set to 1000 rows.

Could anyone please explain why `max.print` option doesn't work to print full dataset in R console? And how can I do that?
I use R 3.4.1 on MacOS.

Here is a data example:

````
1    1 14.23 1.71 2.43 15.6 127 2.80 3.06 0.28 2.29  5.640000 1.040 3.92 1065
2    1 13.20 1.78 2.14 11.2 100 2.65 2.76 0.26 1.28  4.380000 1.050 3.40 1050
3    1 13.16 2.36 2.67 18.6 101 2.80 3.24 0.30 2.81  5.680000 1.030 3.17 1185
4    1 14.37 1.95 2.50 16.8 113 3.85 3.49 0.24 2.18  7.800000 0.860 3.45 1480
5    1 13.24 2.59 2.87 21.0 118 2.80 2.69 0.39 1.82  4.320000 1.040 2.93  735
6    1 14.20 1.76 2.45 15.2 112 3.27 3.39 0.34 1.97  6.750000 1.050 2.85 1450
7    1 14.39 1.87 2.45 14.6  96 2.50 2.52 0.30 1.98  5.250000 1.020 3.58 1290
8    1 14.06 2.15 2.61 17.6 121 2.60 2.51 0.31 1.25  5.050000 1.060 3.58 1295
9    1 14.83 1.64 2.17 14.0  97 2.80 2.98 0.29 1.98  5.200000 1.080 2.85 1045
10   1 13.86 1.35 2.27 16.0  98 2.98 3.15 0.22 1.85  7.220000 1.010 3.55 1045
11   1 14.10 2.16 2.30 18.0 105 2.95 3.32 0.22 2.38  5.750000 1.250 3.17 1510
12   1 14.12 1.48 2.32 16.8  95 2.20 2.43 0.26 1.57  5.000000 1.170 2.82 1280
13   1 13.75 1.73 2.41 16.0  89 2.60 2.76 0.29 1.81  5.600000 1.150 2.90 1320
14   1 14.75 1.73 2.39 11.4  91 3.10 3.69 0.43 2.81  5.400000 1.250 2.73 1150
15   1 14.38 1.87 2.38 12.0 102 3.30 3.64 0.29 2.96  7.500000 1.200 3.00 1547
16   1 13.63 1.81 2.70 17.2 112 2.85 2.91 0.30 1.46  7.300000 1.280 2.88 1310
17   1 14.30 1.92 2.72 20.0 120 2.80 3.14 0.33 1.97  6.200000 1.070 2.65 1280
18   1 13.83 1.57 2.62 20.0 115 2.95 3.40 0.40 1.72  6.600000 1.130 2.57 1130
19   1 14.19 1.59 2.48 16.5 108 3.30 3.93 0.32 1.86  8.700000 1.230 2.82 1680
20   1 13.64 3.10 2.56 15.2 116 2.70 3.03 0.17 1.66  5.100000 0.960 3.36  845
21   1 14.06 1.63 2.28 16.0 126 3.00 3.17 0.24 2.10  5.650000 1.090 3.71  780
22   1 12.93 3.80 2.65 18.6 102 2.41 2.41 0.25 1.98  4.500000 1.030 3.52  770
23   1 13.71 1.86 2.36 16.6 101 2.61 2.88 0.27 1.69  3.800000 1.110 4.00 1035
24   1 12.85 1.60 2.52 17.8  95 2.48 2.37 0.26 1.46  3.930000 1.090 3.63 1015
25   1 13.50 1.81 2.61 20.0  96 2.53 2.61 0.28 1.66  3.520000 1.120 3.82  845
26   1 13.05 2.05 3.22 25.0 124 2.63 2.68 0.47 1.92  3.580000 1.130 3.20  830
27   1 13.39 1.77 2.62 16.1  93 2.85 2.94 0.34 1.45  4.800000 0.920 3.22 1195
28   1 13.30 1.72 2.14 17.0  94 2.40 2.19 0.27 1.35  3.950000 1.020 2.77 1285
29   1 13.87 1.90 2.80 19.4 107 2.95 2.97 0.37 1.76  4.500000 1.250 3.40  915
30   1 14.02 1.68 2.21 16.0  96 2.65 2.33 0.26 1.98  4.700000 1.040 3.59 1035
31   1 13.73 1.50 2.70 22.5 101 3.00 3.25 0.29 2.38  5.700000 1.190 2.71 1285
32   1 13.58 1.66 2.36 19.1 106 2.86 3.19 0.22 1.95  6.900000 1.090 2.88 1515
33   1 13.68 1.83 2.36 17.2 104 2.42 2.69 0.42 1.97  3.840000 1.230 2.87  990
34   1 13.76 1.53 2.70 19.5 132 2.95 2.74 0.50 1.35  5.400000 1.250 3.00 1235
35   1 13.51 1.80 2.65 19.0 110 2.35 2.53 0.29 1.54  4.200000 1.100 2.87 1095
36   1 13.48 1.81 2.41 20.5 100 2.70 2.98 0.26 1.86  5.100000 1.040 3.47  920
37   1 13.28 1.64 2.84 15.5 110 2.60 2.68 0.34 1.36  4.600000 1.090 2.78  880
38   1 13.05 1.65 2.55 18.0  98 2.45 2.43 0.29 1.44  4.250000 1.120 2.51 1105
39   1 13.07 1.50 2.10 15.5  98 2.40 2.64 0.28 1.37  3.700000 1.180 2.69 1020
40   1 14.22 3.99 2.51 13.2 128 3.00 3.04 0.20 2.08  5.100000 0.890 3.53  760
41   1 13.56 1.71 2.31 16.2 117 3.15 3.29 0.34 2.34  6.130000 0.950 3.38  795
42   1 13.41 3.84 2.12 18.8  90 2.45 2.68 0.27 1.48  4.280000 0.910 3.00 1035
43   1 13.88 1.89 2.59 15.0 101 3.25 3.56 0.17 1.70  5.430000 0.880 3.56 1095
44   1 13.24 3.98 2.29 17.5 103 2.64 2.63 0.32 1.66  4.360000 0.820 3.00  680
45   1 13.05 1.77 2.10 17.0 107 3.00 3.00 0.28 2.03  5.040000 0.880 3.35  885
46   1 14.21 4.04 2.44 18.9 111 2.85 2.65 0.30 1.25  5.240000 0.870 3.33 1080
47   1 14.38 3.59 2.28 16.0 102 3.25 3.17 0.27 2.19  4.900000 1.040 3.44 1065
48   1 13.90 1.68 2.12 16.0 101 3.10 3.39 0.21 2.14  6.100000 0.910 3.33  985
49   1 14.10 2.02 2.40 18.8 103 2.75 2.92 0.32 2.38  6.200000 1.070 2.75 1060
50   1 13.94 1.73 2.27 17.4 108 2.88 3.54 0.32 2.08  8.900000 1.120 3.10 1260
51   1 13.05 1.73 2.04 12.4  92 2.72 3.27 0.17 2.91  7.200000 1.120 2.91 1150
52   1 13.83 1.65 2.60 17.2  94 2.45 2.99 0.22 2.29  5.600000 1.240 3.37 1265
53   1 13.82 1.75 2.42 14.0 111 3.88 3.74 0.32 1.87  7.050000 1.010 3.26 1190
54   1 13.77 1.90 2.68 17.1 115 3.00 2.79 0.39 1.68  6.300000 1.130 2.93 1375
55   1 13.74 1.67 2.25 16.4 118 2.60 2.90 0.21 1.62  5.850000 0.920 3.20 1060
56   1 13.56 1.73 2.46 20.5 116 2.96 2.78 0.20 2.45  6.250000 0.980 3.03 1120
57   1 14.22 1.70 2.30 16.3 118 3.20 3.00 0.26 2.03  6.380000 0.940 3.31  970
58   1 13.29 1.97 2.68 16.8 102 3.00 3.23 0.31 1.66  6.000000 1.070 2.84 1270
59   1 13.72 1.43 2.50 16.7 108 3.40 3.67 0.19 2.04  6.800000 0.890 2.87 1285
60   2 12.37 0.94 1.36 10.6  88 1.98 0.57 0.28 0.42  1.950000 1.050 1.82  520
61   2 12.33 1.10 2.28 16.0 101 2.05 1.09 0.63 0.41  3.270000 1.250 1.67  680
62   2 12.64 1.36 2.02 16.8 100 2.02 1.41 0.53 0.62  5.750000 0.980 1.59  450
63   2 13.67 1.25 1.92 18.0  94 2.10 1.79 0.32 0.73  3.800000 1.230 2.46  630
64   2 12.37 1.13 2.16 19.0  87 3.50 3.10 0.19 1.87  4.450000 1.220 2.87  420
65   2 12.17 1.45 2.53 19.0 104 1.89 1.75 0.45 1.03  2.950000 1.450 2.23  355
66   2 12.37 1.21 2.56 18.1  98 2.42 2.65 0.37 2.08  4.600000 1.190 2.30  678
67   2 13.11 1.01 1.70 15.0  78 2.98 3.18 0.26 2.28  5.300000 1.120 3.18  502
68   2 12.37 1.17 1.92 19.6  78 2.11 2.00 0.27 1.04  4.680000 1.120 3.48  510
69   2 13.34 0.94 2.36 17.0 110 2.53 1.30 0.55 0.42  3.170000 1.020 1.93  750
70   2 12.21 1.19 1.75 16.8 151 1.85 1.28 0.14 2.50  2.850000 1.280 3.07  718
71   2 12.29 1.61 2.21 20.4 103 1.10 1.02 0.37 1.46  3.050000 0.906 1.82  870
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 107 rows ]```
````

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in order for the community to give help, include your data

Comment: What is the dimension of your dataframe?

Comment: Corrected my post

Answer (score 2):

> options(max.print = 99999)
>
> ## try this command

Answer (score 0):

Type this code at the start of your R code. Worked for me:

```
options(max.print = .Machine$integer.max)
```

Comment: Please take note that the author explicitly asked for an explanation as well as the code you just posted.